# Terrible sound quality when recording over bluetooth

Tags: audio, bluetooth

I have paired a Jabra Talk 15 headset with a Raspberry Pi 3B (and PulseAudio). I can play sound through the headset well. When I record using `arecord` though, I get almost completely [garbled audio](https://botcompany.de/files/1400342/garbled.wav).

The same headset paired with an Android phone produces great recordings.

Not sure where the problem lies.

[My guess is the Raspi's bluetooth and/or audio stack might just lack a proper codec, but that's only a theory.]

Answer (score 1):

It may have happened because of using `HSP/HFP` or something else. You should use `A2DP` to connect the headset. To do it. check [this link](https://gist.github.com/mill1000/74c7473ee3b4a5b13f6325e9994ff84c) out to configure your raspberry pi.

Comment: Thanks. However, is A2DP not for audio output only? I need input & output like in a phone call.

Comment: Alas yes as [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles#Advanced_Audio_Distribution_Profile_(A2DP)). "*Each A2DP service, of possibly many, is designed to uni-directionally transfer an audio stream in up to 2 channel stereo, either to or from the Bluetooth host.*"